# Angular 4 + Cordova + Device Ready

Tags: angular, cordova, angular-cli

What is the best approach to run (or bootstrapping) an angular-cli based app on Cordova?

Note: This is for an Angular 4.x app for which multiple Cordova plugins are being used.

Option A: Post **ng build**, in your www/index.html (www is Cordova folder) should you do something like:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log('onDeviceReady has been called. Lets start loading JS files.');
  var url = ['inline.bundle.js', 'polyfills.bundle.js', 'styles.bundle.js', 'vendor.bundle.js', 'main.bundle.js'];
  for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
    loadJSFile(url[i]);
  }
}

function loadJSFile(url) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    head.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
```

OR,

Option B: The onDeviceReady() can go somewhere inside main.ts (before bootstrapping AppModule), or app.component.ts.

I have tried Option A, but my app is taking too long to load on iPad. So I wanted to know if I am following a good approach or not. Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach but in my main.ts I added the deviceready event listener with an arrow function which calls the angular bootstrap. It works.

`document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => 
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule), false);`

Comment: I love it! The only way I would improve it, is to first check if `document` is assigned and do the normal bootstrap if not. I know Angular Universal seems to be absolutely nowhere at the moment, but it doesn't hurt to be prepared.

Comment: Even with ionic 4 and angular 7 this is a live saver! Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

If you need to add a check for Cordova as well, you need more complex code. Otherwise Angular will complain about 'Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.'

```
const bootstrap = () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

if (typeof window['cordova'] !== 'undefined') {
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    bootstrap();
  }, false);
} else {
  bootstrap();
}
```

Comment: This version is significantly better than accepted one: it preserves browser debugging and ng serve functionality, while working transparently under Cordova. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In main.ts or main-aot.ts depends how you call your main.ts file

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    console.log("bootstrap device");
    platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
  }, false);
}
```